# How should I handle exception in public int compare()?

Tags: java, exception, compare

I've got the following piece of code:

```
public int compare(Point left, Point right) {
    try {
        // sort points by .x coordinate
        return Integer.compare(left.x, right.x);
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
      // what should I return here? Just a 0 or add some logger warnings?
    }
}
```

What do you think about? What's a good practice of handling exceptions in `compare()`?

Comment: How would that code throw any exception?

Comment: Throw Exception back to caller.. let caller decide what to do next..

Comment: I would, personally, allow the exception to propagate to the caller, since all this is a "convenience" method

Comment: It's an implementation so I can't throw an exception to the caller unfortunately.

Comment: under catch block you can re-throw exception @TonyIvanov

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think the best practice would be to log the error and throw a RuntimeException, or a subclass of it, with the revelant data.

It’s then up to the function caller to decide whether to catch the error and go on with procesing, or to let the exception go up.